# Destrutor de Classe em C++ Chamado no meio do código

Tags: c++

Estou me aprofundando no uso do C++, e estou tendo dificuldade em migrar uma aplicação que usa callbacks e um singleton para gerenciar configurações.

Durante a inicialização do código ainda na função main, crio o singleton responsável pela manutenção das configurações (CycloConfig) e tenho uma função auxiliar que funciona como callback de uma interface gráfica que chama a função correta de uma outra classe conforme determinadas ações do usuário da interface, e assim muda algumas configurações que serão usadas.

Até ai parece tudo bem, porém quando executo a aplicação, na parte quando não uso mais funções que setam valores de configuração na função principal o destrutor está sendo chamado. mas a classe de configuração ainda será usada dentro do callback o que significa que ela é usada a qualquer momento para setar novos valores e este valores são lidos simultaneamente em um loop na função principal.

Já tentei colocar o destrutor no final do código quando a função principal termina, logo antes do return chamando-o configo.~CycloConfig(); e já tirei parâmetros de optimização do código.

Mas mesmo assim ele ainda destrói o objeto quando não o uso mais para setar valores na função principal (main). Apesar de precisar ler os valores que foram atualizados pelo callback.

A objeto criado da classe `CycloConfig` não é passado como parâmetro, uma vez que é um singleton e não pode ser instanciado. apenas obtido através deum factory method:

```
CycloConfig& CycloConfig::get() {
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#warning "Este código é seguro com o uso do C+11, pode haver problemas relativo a concorrencia em verões inferiores."
#endif
    static CycloConfig instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Callback:

```
void MouseCallback(int event, int x, int y,
        int __attribute__((__unused__)) flags,
        void __attribute__((__unused__)) *data) {
    CycloConfig config = CycloConfig::get();
    static InteractionHandler ih(config.getAddress());
    if (ih.hasCurrentCallbackFunction()) {
        switch (event) {
        case (cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN):
            ih.callCurrentCallBack(x, y);
            ih.nextStep();
            break;
        default:
            //printf("Error: MouseCallback: event = %d\n", event);
            //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Inicio da função principal:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    unsigned long debug = 1;

    std::cout << "*****************************************************"
            << std::endl;
    std::cout << "** Obtendo configurações                           **"
            << std::endl;
    CycloConfig config = CycloConfig::get();
    std::cout << "** configurações carregadas                        **"
            << std::endl;
    std::cout.flush();
...
```

Fim da Função principal:

```
...

    delete cap;
    if (outputDevice)
        delete outputDevice;
    if (outputFile)
        delete outputFile;

    config.~CycloConfig();
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Construtores e destrutores da Classe de Configuração:

```
CycloConfig::CycloConfig() {
    this->LoadData();
    std::cout << "** CycloConfig> Criado." << std::endl;
}

CycloConfig::~CycloConfig() {
    this->PersistData();
    std::cout << "** CycloConfig> Descartado." << std::endl;

}
...
class CycloConfig {
private:
    const char *configFile = "CycloTracker.conf";
    ConfigData data;

    CycloConfig();

public:
    virtual ~CycloConfig();

    void PersistData();
    void LoadData();

    static CycloConfig& get();
```

Comment: Existem muito poucas ocasiões onde você deve chamar o destrutor explicitamente, e a sua não é uma delas. É bem provável que seu objeto esteja sendo copiado ser passado de parâmetro para alguma função, e esta cópia esteja sendo destruída. Mostre um pouco de código, principalmente trechos que passem seu singleton como parâmetro ou retorno. Assim vai ser mais fácil dar uma ajuda mais concreta.

Comment: Olá, adicionei alguns códigos espero que sejam suficientes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema encontra-se na forma como você está acessando seu objeto *singleton*. A função de acesso está corretamente retornando o objeto por referência mas, tanto na função `MouseCallback` quanto na `main` estão sendo declaradas variáveis "normais" do objeto, que acabam gerando cópias dele. E no momento que estas cópias saem de escopo elas são destruídas, fazendo com que o destrutor seja chamado.

A solução simples é apenas mudar a declaração das variáveis locais para um tipo referência, ou ponteiro:

```
CycloConfig config = CycloConfig::get(); //Cópia

CycloConfig &config = CycloConfig::get(); //Referência

CycloConfig *config = &CycloConfig::get(); //Ponteiro
```

C++ trata primariamente objetos definidos pelo usuário da mesma forma que os tipos básicos da linguagem. Então, da mesma forma, se houvesse uma função retornando uma referência para um `int` e seu valor fosse atribuído a uma variável local, esta variável é uma cópia, completamente independente da referência original.

Para tipos simples, a destruição é trivial e a cópia é feita pela simples replicação dos bits, mas para tipos definidos pelo usuário podem ser definidos destrutores, construtores de cópia e operadores de atribuição. Se não forem definidos, o compilador os gera automaticamente. Mas, para *singletons* e outros casos especiais, é possível suprimir esta geração:

```
class CycloConfig {
    ....
    //Desabilita Construtor de Cópia gerado pelo compilador
    CycloConfig(const CycloConfig &) = delete;

    //Desabilita Operador de Atribuição gerado pelo compilador
    CycloConfig &operator=(const CycloConfig &) = delete;
    ....
};
```

Desta forma, caso se tente copiar o objeto inadvertidamente (como aconteceu no problema) o compilador irá impedir, avisando que as operações de cópia foram desabilitadas pelo usuário.

Comment: Usei a opção por referência e o problema persiste. Fiz um log de passos: https://gist.github.com/carlosdelfino/26a9518c7c7e776ee3970d30bf6d74b7

Comment: @Delfino Já tentou mudar sua classe para "deletar" as operações de cópia?

Comment: Como assim?, no link acima do gist eu coloquei o arquivo principal onde o problema ocorre. ele ainda está bastante confuso porque estou migrando e limpando o código aos poucos.

Comment: Veja a parte final da resposta, eu fiz uma atualização. Faça aquilo para garantir que não estejam sendo criadas cópias em nenhum outro lugar. Além disso você ainda está chamando explicitamente o destrutor no final da função main, o que é errado.

Comment: o problema está resolvido.
100% Obrigado.